# Is stringifying a state object an efficient approach for avoiding infinite loop in useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I stringified my user state object to be able to set it as the dependency of my useEffect and not trigger an infinite loop. Yet, I'm wondering how efficient is this design. Is JSON.stringify an expensive operation? Any ideas for a better design?

```
  const user = useContext(UserCtx);
  const stringifiedUser = JSON.stringify(user);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user === null) {
      router.push("/login");
    }
  }, [stringifiedUser])
```

Comment: The best solution would probably be to modify your context to provide a stable `user` reference. A memoized value might be the correct tool for that situation

Comment: You are not updating `user` inside your `useEffect`, so even if you had it in the dependency as it is, there is no problem.

Comment: You're right I meant to avoid unnecessary rerenders.